# Problems with R package dependencies

Tags: r, package

I created a n R package which has certain dependencies on other packages.
So i specified the package name as Imports and Depends in the Description file.
In the namespace file I specified that the package should be exported.
I checked the writing R extensions manual and there doesn't seem to be anything else that I should add.

When I try running the package it is not able to call the functions on which the package depends.Do I need to specify additional parameters to be able to call those functions.

I am using R version 2.15.0

Please help me out with this problem.

Thanks.

```
NAMESPACE:
import("RHive")
export("bigEDA")
export("procFreq")
export("procUnivariate")
```

I want all the functions from RHive to be present in the same environment as my package.
Just not able to do that.
I have tried specifying `export("RHive")` and `exportFrom("RHive","rhive.query")`
This also doesn't work. :(

Comment: In your NAMESPACE file you should export functions, not your package. Consider posting your DESCRIPTION and perhaps an extract from NAMESPACE in your question, so we can see what you have tried.

Comment: you can specify both, if i specify export it should export all user level functions.
I have tried exportFrom adding all the functions that I need in that,doesn't seem to work.
I guess that's what you were mentioning, if not please explain more.

Comment: To export all functions in the package, you either need to list each exported function, or use a regular expression. Post your NAMESPACE file in your question so we can see what you have done.

Comment: added the namespace file in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `R CMD check NAMEofYOURpackage` in your terminal or shell to test whether your DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE file are fine? This check routine creates the file 00install.out that can give you a hint where something went wrong.

If you just want to use functions from foreign packages in your package use the DESCRIPTION file. There you just type: `Depends: RHive`

Use the `export` in the NAMESPACE file to export your functions to the user. If you have a function `sum()` and you want the user who installed your package to be able to use this function use: `exportMethods(sum)` (you can add more functions right here by separating them with commas)

Comment: Yes i did all that , the description file has all the depends. The R CMD check works perefctly fine.It doesn't work.
I know I don't need to specify an export for functions in an existing package, just need to specify depends or imports in the description file.
There is something ither than that wrong.I have been trying to figure that out for 2 weeks now.

Comment: What if I am using roxygen2 for doing NAMESPACE. (and I see problems with export)